Why were humans in the Starcraft universe called Terrans?
Why were humans in the Starcraft universe called Terrans? Why not humans or man? At least in the Koprulu sector, the inhabitants weren't aware that their species are supposed to be called humans. Or this a different species, like a subspecies of humanity in deep space?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terran

Every sentient species calls themselves "man" or something equivalent; that's not specific. Naming your species after the originating planet is. (I understand that likewise, every species calls their planet the local equivalent of "Earth" or "Ground"; but somehow, that's a proper name and more distinguishable.) It's a bit like every town -- like Berlin -- in Germany calls their specialty dough thing "pancake"; but everywhere outside Berlin it is called *Berliner", to distinguish it from the other "pancakes". The Amazon tribe is called "Amazonians" only elsewhere.

Incidentally, Earth is called Terra in WH40k universe, which SC is heavily "inspired" by

Earth's Latin name is Terra, ergo, humans that come from Earth are Terrans.
This is not a Starcraft-universe thing; humans (or human constructs/organizations) are also called Terrans in a variety of other science fiction contexts, as you can see from the link.

This was quite normal usage in sf when I got started in the 1950s. Once I even saw it used in a non-fiction book about space travel. Perhaps it was a way for the authors to convey that thhey were educated men who could be taken seriously. E E "Doc" Smith used "Tellus" and "Tellurian" in a similar way.

I suspect it started in stories where humans were on multiple planets and there needed to be some way to distinguish humans living on Earth from those living on Mars or Jupiter. So not all humans would be Terrans, just the ones on Earth.

Searching on google books for "terran" between 1905 and 1950 I do see examples of that, and also examples where "Terran" is used more generally to refer to any life originating from Earth, not just humans. I also see that the "Journal of the British Interplanetary Society" uses the word "Terran" in an apparently scientific context in 1934 to describe Earth-like planets.

Please forgive the nitpicks, but: the original question (which has been rewritten since I originally wrote my answer) asks both "Are they a different species?" and says "They weren't aware they're humans." This answer doesn't actually address either of those points.

"Earth's Latin name is Terra, ergo, humans that come from Earth are Terrans" — big spacefarers, the Romans.

The question is slightly unclear as written, but seems to be claiming that the human inhabitants of the Koprulu Sector are not aware of their history and origins, and therefore should not know to identify themselves as "Terran."
This is not the case.
One can download the original Starcraft manual from Blizzard and learn that the 40,000 colonists ultimately sent to the Koprulu sector as part of Project Purification were quite aware of their origins. The people who ended up in the Koprulu Sector all originated on Earth. They were, variously, "dissidents, hackers, synthetics, the cybernetically enhanced, tech-pirates, and criminals of every kind."
The humans who arrived in the Koprulu Sector are consistently identified as "Terrans" in the text. The manual does not explicitly give a reason for this, but we can easily extrapolate an explanation. All the colonists sent to Koprulu were all fully aware they came from Earth, a.k.a. Terra, and that information was available in ATLAS (the supercomputer that oversaw the journey) as well. Although the text does not directly address this, ATLAS clearly contained extensive stores of data, given that colonization was the mission's primary purpose.
The ship carrying the main ATLAS supercomputer landed on Tarsonis, and the manual text strongly implies that the Tarsonis colony's primacy over the other colonies was due to the "leg up" advantage of having access to ATLAS and its stores of data while the other colonies did not.
Relevant quotes from the manual:

Cataloguing the various mutations and cybernetic enhancements of the prisoners, Route input all of the data into a revolutionary supercomputer. This Artificial Tele-empathic Logistics Analysis System, known as ATLAS, ...


Only 40,000 of the prisoners were deemed viable to survive the rigorous conditions. Those 40,000 were then loaded onto four gargantuan, automated deep-space supercarriers.


The ATLAS was installed into the first of the supercarriers, the Nagglfar.


They accessed ATLAS directly and confirmed their growing suspicions that they would never see the Earth again.


Tarsonis, the largest and most technologically advanced of the colonies, ...


The fleets of Tarsonis continued to explore the Terran patch of space that came to be known as the Koprulu Sector.

So, TL;DR:

All the humans in the Koprulu sector know they're from Earth.
Earth is known as Terra.
They decided to call themselves Terran, presumably because they originated from Terra.


And just to add, a second exploratory force under the flag of the United Earth Directorate arrived during the Broodwars. So the term "Earth" was definitely (still) in use, but it's likely the colonists intentionally abandoned it, possibly due to being basically outcasts.

Out of universe, Blizzard may have wanted to distinguish StarCraft from Warcraft, where the first installment was titled "Warcraft: Orcs & Humans".
When an early version of StarCraft was first unveiled, it was derided as being a knockoff Warcraft and dubbed "Orcs in Space", so Blizzard intentionally made changes to differentiate it from Warcraft. This may have included choosing a name for the human faction ("Terrans") that differed from the human faction in the Warcraft games, where they were simply called "Humans".

'Terran 'also sounds more Sci-Fi than 'Human'
